# Making a dataframe with columns as subsets of another dataframe's columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, subset

Suppose I have a dataframe df, and it has columns with names 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'.  Then I make all combinations of length three (order doesn't matter) from this list to generate the following list of lists:
Combinations_of_3 = [ [['a','b','c'], ['a','b','d'],...., ['c','d','e']]]

Now I wish to create a for loop to populate a second data frame, and to do this I want to loop over Combinations_of_3 and use the current entry to select the corresponding columns of df.
For example, if I wanted to select only the 'a', 'b' and 'e' columns of df, I would normally write df[['a','b','e']]; but now I would like to do this in a for loop using Combinations_of_3.  I'm writing this code using pandas / python.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just do as you described, using a variable:

```
Combinations_of_3 = [['a','b','c'], ['a','b','d'], ['c','d','e']]

for cols in Combinations_of_3:
    #do something
    print(df[cols])
```

*NB. To create Combinations_of_3 you could use*:

```
from itertools import combinations

Combinations_of_3 = list(combinations(df.columns, r=3))

#or using a generator
Combinations_of_3 = combinations(df.columns, r=3)
```